# Using tempfile to create pdf/xls documents in flask

Tags: python, excel, pdf, flask, temporary-files

I wanted to ask if it's possible to create PDF/XLS documents as temporary files. I'm doing that to send them using flask afterwards. For pdf/xls files creation I use **reportlab** and **xlsxwriter** packages respectively. When I save document using their methods, I get the "Python temporary file permission denied" error. When I try to close using the **tempfile** methods, files become corrupted. Is there any way to overcome this? Or any other suitable solution?

**EDIT:**

Some code snippets:

```
import xlswriter
import tempfile
from flask import after_this_request


@app.route('/some_url', method=['POST'])
def create_doc_function():
    @after_this_request
    def cleanup(response):
        temp.close()
        return response

    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(temp.name)
    # some actions here ...
    book.close()  # raises "Python temporaty file permission denied" error.
                  # If missed, Excel book is gonna be corrupted, 
                  # i.e. blank, which make sense
    return send_file(temp, as_attachment=True, 
                     attachment_filename='my_document_name.xls')
```

Similar story with pdf files.

Comment: Could you post an example of the code you have so far?

Comment: thanks! My answer below which uses a persistent temp file should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tempfile.mkstemp()` which will create a standard temp file on disk which will persist until removed:

```
import tempfile
import os

handle, filepath = tempfile.mkstemp()
f = os.fdopen(handle)  # convert raw handle to file object
...
```

EDIT
`tempfile.TemporaryFile()` will be destroyed as soon as it's closed, which is why your code above is failing.

Comment: Thank you, this was a good starting point. I found more here: https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/17873

Comment: or use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

Answer (score 0):

You can use and delete *NamedTemporaryFile* with context manager (or atexit module). It may do the dirty job for you.
**Example 1:**

```
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

# define class, because everyone loves objects
class FileHandler():

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Let's create temporary file in constructor
        Notice that there is no param (delete=True is not necessary) 
        '''
        self.file = NamedTemporaryFile()

    # write something funny into file...or do whatever you need
    def write_into(self, btext):
        self.file.write(btext)

    def __enter__(self):
        '''
        Define simple but mandatory __enter__ function - context manager will require it.
        Just return the instance, nothing more is requested.
        '''
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        '''
        Also define mandatory __exit__ method which is called at the end.
        NamedTemporaryFile is deleted as soon as is closed (function checks it before and after close())
        '''
        print('Calling __exit__:')
        print(f'File exists = {os.path.exists(self.file.name)}')
        self.file.close()
        print(f'File exists = {os.path.exists(self.file.name)}')


# use context mamager 'with' to create new instance and do something
with FileHandler() as fh:
    fh.write_into(b'Hi happy developer!')

print(f'\nIn this point {fh.file.name} does not exist (exists = {os.path.exists(fh.file.name)})')
```

Output:

```
Calling __exit__:
File exists = True
File exists = False

In this point D:\users\fll2cj\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyv37sp58 does not exist (exists = False)
```

Or you can use *atexit* module which calls defined function when program (cmd) exits.
**Example 2:**

```
import os, atexit
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

class FileHandler():

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = NamedTemporaryFile()
        # register function called when quit
        atexit.register(self._cleanup)

    def write_into(self, btext):
        self.file.write(btext)

    def _cleanup(self):
        # because self.file has been created without delete=False, closing the file causes its deletion 
        self.file.close()

# create new instance and do whatever you need
fh = FileHandler()
fh.write_into(b'Hi happy developer!')
# now the file still exists, but when program quits, _cleanup() is called and file closed and automaticaly deleted.
```