# return a created excel file with flask

Tags: python, excel, flask, openpyxl, pyexcel

I am creating a excel file using openpyxl which I would like to return as a file download (so not saving locally).

I can create the excel file fine and save it to disk. However, I cannot get this file to download.

Attempt 1:

```
import flask_excel as excel

...

create_excel_sheet(data) # internally save the sheet with name sheet.xlsx

output = excel.make_response()
output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + \
                                        'sheet.xlsx'
output.headers["Content-type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-\
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

return output
```

This returns an empty text file with name sheet.xlsx

Attempt 2:
    wb = create_excel_sheet(data) # return openpyxl workbook

```
output = excel.make_response(wb)
output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + \
                                        'sheet.xlsx'
output.headers["Content-type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-\
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

return output
```

I don't want to use pyexcel for the data as I need openpyxl to create a fancy excel sheet. Obviously if pyexcel and openpyxl communicated that would be fine.

any thoughts?

Cheers, Mike

Comment: openpyxl does allow you to save to a file like object with `save_virtual_workbook()`

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Charlie Clark's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42962788/248616), I finally settled on the following solution.

```
output = make_response(create_sheet(data))
output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + \
                                        "sheet.xlsx"
output.headers["Content-type"] = \
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

where

```
def create_sheet(data):
```

returns

```
return save_virtual_workbook(wb)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since I struggled with ambiguity to reassemble fragmented and a little bit old-fashioned code snippets, I want to leave another answer here. This is technically the same but a quite complete code snippet which is a little bit more up to date.

```
from flask import Response
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

...

@app.route("/download")
def download():
    wb = Workbook()
    
    ...

    return Response(
        save_virtual_workbook(wb),
        headers={
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=sheet.xlsx',
            'Content-type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did when I faced the same problem is that I wrote a temporary file on the server, I made my `create_excel_sheet(data)` function to return file name and then send the file back with the flask `send_file()` function:

```
send_file( create_excel_sheet_and_return_filename(data) )
```

You can use python modules that create temporary files which are deleted when the process exists and use authorization if security is an issue.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, but now my tempfiles are adding up in my /tmp/dir . I used the approach in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391344/using-tempfile-to-create-pdf-xls-documents-in-flask

Comment: did you create the named temporary file with delete=True? https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile

Answer (score 1):

That all *looks* correct. Are you actually returning the response from your view? That wasn't clear in the question, and would explain the problem, I think.

For example:

```
@app.route('/download_sheet')
def download():
    create_excel_sheet(data)
    output = excel.make_response()
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=sheet.xlsx"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-\
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    return output  # Send the response to the user
```

...

```
<a href="{{ url_for('app.download') }}">Click here for Sheet</a>
```

Comment: I do return output (edited above). My problem (now) is to return the file without filling my memory with temporaries

Comment: Hm -- It seems like the temporary file solution is working. So, how about you just have the app search for and remove temporary files at regular intervals?