How can i make a dropdown field in xlsx file with python?
Im making a website and i want to be able to import employees with an excel file, so im trying to make it so that there is a dropdown with all the departments. Assume you get all the department names with Department.get_all_departments(), how can i make the excel file have a dropdown field with those names using python?
Here is some code chat gpt generated that doesnt work:
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

# Create a new Workbook and select the active worksheet
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Set the text "Department" in cell A1
ws['A1'] = 'Department'

# Define the dropdown options and store them in cells B1 and B2
dropdown_options = Department.get_all_departments()
for index, option in enumerate(dropdown_options, start=1):
    ws[f'B{index}'] = option

# Create a DataValidation object that references the cells B1:B2
# Important: Use a formula that includes the sheet name if necessary
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=$B$1:$B$2', showDropDown=True)

# Optionally add a message to guide the user
dv.prompt = "Please select a department from the dropdown list"
dv.promptTitle = "Department List"

# Apply the DataValidation to cell A2
ws.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add(ws["A2"])

# Save the Workbook to a file
wb.save("department_dropdown_fixed.xlsx")



showDropDown=True actually disables the  'in-cell dropdown' check box, so remove it. From the Openpyxl Docs Note Excel and LibreOffice interpret the parameter showDropDown=True as the dropdown arrow should be hidden.

There is no need to write the actual options to file, you can hand them over in the DataValidation construction, see the documentation. Also there is no point in adding showDropDown=True. Try something like this:
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# set text
ws['A1'] = 'Department'

# set dropdown
dropdown_options = Department.get_all_departments()
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=f'"{",".join(dropdown_options)}"')
ws.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add(ws["A2"])

wb.save("department_dropdown_fixed.xlsx")


Thanks bro that solved it for me!!
How can i use the flask make_response() so people can download it?

@RaptoRR Wrap the above code into a routing method in a controller class, and then try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63241255/18189622
