# Have Flask return a excel file in xlsx format as output

Tags: python, excel, pandas, flask

I have an excel spreadsheet with the extension of `.xlsx`. I am trying to have this returned as part of my Flask project.

I have the below code that I am trying but I keep getting an error

```
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Given below is the code:

```
file = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter')
resp = make_response(file.to_excel(writer))
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=output.xlsx"
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
return resp
```

Comment: You must return a string or function, You are trying to return an object here

Comment: @min2bro could you I am just trying to have the excel file returned. I thought the variable `resp` would help me do that. Could you please advice as to where am I going wrong on this. Thanks.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391344/using-tempfile-to-create-pdf-xls-documents-in-flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `send_file` from flask lib.

Here is an example:

```
from flask import send_file
@routes.route("/files/download", methods=['GET'])
def download():
    file_path = '/your/file/path'
    return send_file(
        file_path,
        mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: thank you that helped..